# Extracting data from XML using OpenXML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openxml, xml-nil

I have a xml which I want it to be extracted using OpenXML within SQL Server

Here is the sample XML

```
<row>
  <student_token>7</student_token>
  <student_ssn>552</student_ssn>
  <alternate_id>20</alternate_id>
  <old_ssn xsi:nil="true" />
  <alien_num xsi:nil="true" />
  <last_name>A</last_name>
  <first_name>B</first_name>
  <middle_init xsi:nil="true" />
  <drivers_license_num xsi:nil="true" />
  <gpa_highschool xsi:nil="true" />
  <created_dt>2006-07-13T11:15:08.320</created_dt>
  <created_how>4</created_how>
  <modified_dt>2008-02-14T00:00:00</modified_dt>
  <modified_by>4</modified_by>
  <primary_street2 xsi:nil="true" />
  <primary_street3 xsi:nil="true" />
  <primary_country xsi:nil="true" />
  <email_address xsi:nil="true" />
  <address_start_dt xsi:nil="true" />
  <address_end_dt xsi:nil="true" />
  <entrance_iv_dt xsi:nil="true" />
  <entrance_iv_by xsi:nil="true" />
  <exit_iv_dt>2006-11-02T00:00:00</exit_iv_dt>
  <exit_iv_by>156</exit_iv_by>
  <foreign_address_indicator>N</foreign_address_indicator>
  <foreign_postal_code xsi:nil="true" />
  <pin>J27841</pin>
  <web_id>J08614   </web_id>
  <prior_name xsi:nil="true" />
  <orig_eps xsi:nil="true" />
  <web_role>STU1</web_role>
  <heal_limit_flag>N</heal_limit_flag>
  <email_address_2>test@test.com</email_address_2>
  <cellular_telephone>415</cellular_telephone>
  <alt_loan_debt xsi:nil="true" />
  <web_last_login xsi:nil="true" />
  <foreign_country_code xsi:nil="true" />
  <entrance_iv_dt_grad_plus xsi:nil="true" />
  <entrance_iv_by_grad_plus xsi:nil="true" />
  <failed_logins>0</failed_logins>
  <hispanic xsi:nil="true" />
  <race xsi:nil="true" />
  <primary_phone_number_intl xsi:nil="true" />
  <security_version>0</security_version>
  <failed_challenge_response>0</failed_challenge_response>
  <require_pin_reset xsi:nil="true" />
</row>
```

The query should extract into 3 fields for each row

1. FieldName
2. FieldValue
3. IsNull

For example the first row should be

- FieldName = student_token - The node name would be the field name
- FieldValue = 7
- IsNull = false - IsNull is based on the attribute  xsi:nil="true"

How can I do this?

Comment: The tag name is the FieldName and ISNull is based on the Attribute  xsi:nil="true"

Comment: The result should take the element name from each node and return that as the FieldName. For example the first row fieldname would be student_token and the next one would be student_ssn and the next would be alternate_id ....

Comment: You mean use the first element name and use that as the FieldName?  There are multiple xsi:nil.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sample data with namespace added.

```
declare @xml xml 
set @xml = 
'<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <student_token>7</student_token>
  <student_ssn>552</student_ssn>
  <alternate_id>20</alternate_id>
  <old_ssn xsi:nil="true" />
  <alien_num xsi:nil="true" />
  <last_name>A</last_name>
  <first_name>B</first_name>
  <middle_init xsi:nil="true" />
  <drivers_license_num xsi:nil="true" />
  <gpa_highschool xsi:nil="true" />
  <created_dt>2006-07-13T11:15:08.320</created_dt>
  <created_how>4</created_how>
  <modified_dt>2008-02-14T00:00:00</modified_dt>
  <modified_by>4</modified_by>
  <primary_street2 xsi:nil="true" />
  <primary_street3 xsi:nil="true" />
  <primary_country xsi:nil="true" />
  <email_address xsi:nil="true" />
  <address_start_dt xsi:nil="true" />
  <address_end_dt xsi:nil="true" />
  <entrance_iv_dt xsi:nil="true" />
  <entrance_iv_by xsi:nil="true" />
  <exit_iv_dt>2006-11-02T00:00:00</exit_iv_dt>
  <exit_iv_by>156</exit_iv_by>
  <foreign_address_indicator>N</foreign_address_indicator>
  <foreign_postal_code xsi:nil="true" />
  <pin>J27841</pin>
  <web_id>J08614   </web_id>
  <prior_name xsi:nil="true" />
  <orig_eps xsi:nil="true" />
  <web_role>STU1</web_role>
  <heal_limit_flag>N</heal_limit_flag>
  <email_address_2>test@test.com</email_address_2>
  <cellular_telephone>415</cellular_telephone>
  <alt_loan_debt xsi:nil="true" />
  <web_last_login xsi:nil="true" />
  <foreign_country_code xsi:nil="true" />
  <entrance_iv_dt_grad_plus xsi:nil="true" />
  <entrance_iv_by_grad_plus xsi:nil="true" />
  <failed_logins>0</failed_logins>
  <hispanic xsi:nil="true" />
  <race xsi:nil="true" />
  <primary_phone_number_intl xsi:nil="true" />
  <security_version>0</security_version>
  <failed_challenge_response>0</failed_challenge_response>
  <require_pin_reset xsi:nil="true" />
</row>'
```

Using `openxml`.

```
declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @xml, '<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'

select FieldName, 
       FieldValue,
       isnull([IsNull], 0)
from openxml(@idoc, '/row/*',1) 
  with (
         FieldName  varchar(50) '@mp:localname',
         FieldValue varchar(50) '.',
         [IsNull]   bit         '@xsi:nil'
       )

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

Using the XML data type:

```
;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') as FieldName,
       T.N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as FieldValue,
       isnull(T.N.value('@ns:nil', 'bit'), 0) as [IsNull]
from @xml.nodes('/row/*') as T(N)
```

Comment: @marc_s - Is the URL the same in the XML as in the `sp_xml_preparedocument` statement?

Comment: oops - no! :-) I had set it myself to just whatever - of course that doesn't match up with your setting! :-) Sorry, my bad..... works like a charm now!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you have that XML as a SQL variable or inside a table - question is very unclear .....

If you have it as an SQL variable, then try something like this (*note: you **must** declare the `xsi` prefix somehow - otherwise SQL Server's XML processor won't even look at your XML document*):

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <student_token>7</student_token>
  <student_ssn>552</student_ssn>
  <alternate_id>20</alternate_id>
  <old_ssn xsi:nil="true" />
  .........
</row>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi)
SELECT
FieldName = T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
FieldValue = T.C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(500)'),
IsNIL = ISNULL(T.C.value('(@xsi:nil)[1]', 'bit'), 0)
FROM
@Input.nodes('/row/*') AS T(C)
```

This gives me an output something like:

```
FieldName      FieldValue  IsNIL
student_token    7          0
student_ssn      552        0
alternate_id     20         0
old_ssn                     1
.....
```

Of course, all output is going to be of type `varchar(500)` now in the `FieldValue` column....

Updated my answer, based on Mikael Eriksson's answer, to include the `IsNIL` handling, too. Thanks Mikael for the inspiration! You deserve the nod and the accept vote!

Comment: The reason for using OpenXml was performance. Isn't this slower than openxml?

Comment: @Rush - I think that would be an interesting question on SO. It's been on my todo list for a while to check what is the fastest. I have read that they should be almost the same but ... needs some testing.

Comment: @Rush: no, not necessarily. Both approaches have their pros and cons - but the OpenXML is definitely more resource intensive (with the call to `sp_xml_preparedocument`) and less intuitive (at least to me)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `xml` file to `json` and then use `OPENJSON` instead. Take a look at [openjson : SELECT star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61497304/openjson-select-star) on how to use OPENJSON without having to list column names.

To convert an `xml` file to `json` you can use `sp_execute_external_script` and the `xmltodict` python module.
Take a look at [Importing Python Libraries to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731713/importing-python-libraries-to-sql-server/61639570#61639570) to import the python module and deal with YAPI (Yet Another Python Install) issues.