# openjson : SELECT star

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, open-json

I have a table in a json file (C:\db.json):

```
[{"_id":"81743561","_record_number":"1","_form_id":"618213","_user_id":"218754",...},
{"_id":"81782299","_record_number":"2","_form_id":"618213","_user_id":"218754",...},
{"_id":"81784481","_record_number":"3","_form_id":"618213","_user_id":"218754",...}]
```

It has about 60 "columns". I have a 100 "tables" like this to import into SQL Server, each with its own schema.
I found it could be done this way:

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\db.json', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
WITH 
(
    _id integer,
    _record_number integer,
    _form_id integer,
    _user_id integer,
    ...
)
```

I really need to avoid manually writing the list of columns. One option is to parse the json and generate the column list. Before I start going down that road, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid listing the columns, something equivalent to a `SELECT *` ?

Comment: Probably a dynamic statement is an option. `OPENJSON` with default schema (without the `WITH` clause) returns one row for each `key: value` pair for each object in the JSON array. And the return values are `varchar\nvarchar`. What are the expected data type for the results from `OPENJSON` call  - always integer? And what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: if column data type is varchar(max) by default, it would be ok. I tried without the WITH clause, it only produced 3 columns (key, value, type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to build and execute a dynamic statement, because `OPENJSON()` with default schema (without the `WITH` clause) returns a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and one row for each `"key": "value"` pair for each object in the input `JSON` array. So, you need an explicit schema. To build that schema dynamically, you need to parse the first item from the whole JSON array using `OPENJSON()` with a default schema.

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max)

SET @json = N'[
   {"_id":"81743561","_record_number":"1","_form_id":"618213","_user_id":"218754"},
   {"_id":"81782299","_record_number":"2","_form_id":"618213","_user_id":"218754"},
   {"_id":"81784481","_record_number":"3","_form_id":"618213","_user_id":"218754"}
]'
-- Or read JSON from file
-- SELECT @json = BulkColumn
-- FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\db.json', SINGLE_CLOB)

DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) 

SELECT @stm = STRING_AGG(CAST([key] + ' varchar(max) ' AS varchar(max)), ', ')
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0]')

SET @stm = N'SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@json) WITH (' + @stm + N')'

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm, N'@json varchar(max)', @json
```

Result:

```
_id      _record_number _form_id    _user_id
81743561 1              618213      218754
81782299 2              618213      218754
81784481 3              618213      218754
```